# vnext (asp .net 5.0) and oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net, c#-5.0

I created a vnext solution in visual studio ultimate 2015 CTP version 14.0.22609.0 D14REL and in the package manager I added the oracle managed driver.

```
Install-Package odp.net.managed
```

then in my config.json

```
"Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-vnext-237fb18c-c414-44a8-8771-e02d4719d1dc;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        },
        "hr": {
            "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mydatabase))); User Id=hr; Password=xxxxxxx;", "providerName":"oracle.manaagedatacess.client"
        }

    },
```

when I attempted to use it in a class

```
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Configuration;

namespace vnext.Models
{
    internal class dataHelper
    {
        OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hr"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

lots of compile errors such as the type or namespace Oracle, Configuration, and OracleConnection could not be found are you missing an assembly reference? project vnext asp.net Core 5.0

Comment: A few things - that is not the "Official" Oracle Nuget package. Look for the official one which does configuration for you. Also, VS 2015 is not yet supported, meaning there could be issues. I wouldn't waste much time with the CTP until it goes production unless you really have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Shay is right... But there is a tweak. I didn't tested but just try to comment the dnxcore50 in project.json as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": { } 
 },
```

Since the default web template targets both the full .NET and .NET Core, the oracle managed driver framework is currently not available in .NET Core. so you can comment it out. Now you should be able to build and run the solution with out error.

Update :
Removed 
    `/* dnxcore50": { } */`

Comment: cool thanks I'll give it a shot tonight.  although I don't really need it anymore I was doing a demo at work and was attempting to show a vnext solution in the what's coming down the pike section of the demo and we are an oracle shop so I was attempting to make it work with Oracle

Comment: Comments are no longer supported in the project.json file, so you actually need to delete that entry.  See this for a discussion: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1816